# How to test custom repository layer without database? Tests are passing, but methods are not getting coverage

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, keystore

I am working on a repository that implements Java Cryptography Architecture and manages keys in a keystore file. I am trying to avoid using external dependencies when testing, therefore using mock tests. However these do not seem to show up when checking for test coverage. Only the tests that are direcrly linked to the source code without using mock seem to be covered.

I would like to mocking in my tests and still achieve test coverage. I have tried using Mockito, Powermock, Powermockito.

Ive also tried using varius mocking methods for the repository like:
`private final EncryptionRepositoryImpl encryptionRepositoryMock = mock(EncryptionRepositoryImpl.class);`

```
@SpringBootTest
public class When_managing_keys {

    @MockBean
    private KeyManagementRepositoryImpl keyManagementRepository;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void when_getting_key_aliases() throws Exception {
        List<String> keyAliases = new ArrayList<>();
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());

        Mockito.when(keyManagementRepository.getKeyAliases()).thenReturn(keyAliases);

        KeyManagementRepositoryImpl repoFromContext = context.getBean(KeyManagementRepositoryImpl.class);
        List<String> keyAliasesRes = repoFromContext.getKeyAliases();

        assertEquals(keyAliases, keyAliasesRes);
        Mockito.verify(keyManagementRepository).getKeyAliases();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test has some mistakes. Let's do a step-by-step below:

1. You're creating a mock instance (`keyManagementRepository`) for the type `KeyManagementRepositoryImpl`

```java
@MockBean
private KeyManagementRepositoryImpl keyManagementRepository;
```

2. Then you mock the return whenever the method `getKeyAliases()` from the `keyManagementRepository` instance is called;

```java
Mockito.when(keyManagementRepository.getKeyAliases()).thenReturn(keyAliases);
```

3. Then you create a new instance (`repoFromContext`) for the type `KeyManagementRepositoryImpl` and call the method `getKeyAliases` from this instance.

```java
KeyManagementRepositoryImpl repoFromContext = context.getBean(KeyManagementRepositoryImpl.class);
List<String> keyAliasesRes = repoFromContext.getKeyAliases();
```

The above line calls the method from the instance you create (`repoFromContext`), **not from your mocked instance (`keyManagementRepository`)**, you see?

I would suggest you `@Autowire` the service or whatever component you have that makes the call to your `KeyManagementRepositoryImpl`, inject your mocked repository in this component, and then call the method in this component that calls the `getKeyAliases`. It will use the return you configured in the `Mockito.when` call.

Comment: Hello, I've tried implementing the changes you described. The test does pass, but yet again it does not get coverage. Here are my changes:

```
    @InjectMocks
    KeyManagementServiceImpl keyManagementService;
    @Mock
    KeyManagementRepositoryImpl keyManagementRepository;
    @Test
    public void test()  {
        //generating keyAliases arraylist here
        when(keyManagementRepository.getKeyAliases()).thenReturn(keyAliases);
        List<String> keyAliasesRes = keyManagementService.getKeyAliases();
        assertEquals(keyAliases, keyAliasesRes);

    }

```

Comment: Thank you for youre help, hope you get a chance to look at this @Vitor Cavalcanti

Comment: Instead of constructing your `KeyManagementService` by using `@InjectMocks`, try to construct the instance passing your mocked repository in the constructor of your service. Something like that: `KeyManagementService keyManagementService = new KeyManagementServiceImpl(keyManagementRepository);`.

Comment: We tried implementing this, but the test are still noe getting coverage. 

@Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> keyAliases = new ArrayList<>();
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());
        keyAliases.add(randomUUID().toString());
        Mockito.when(keyManagementRepository.getKeyAliases()).thenReturn(keyAliases);
        List<String> keyAliasesRes = keyManagementService.getKeyAliases();
        assertEquals(keyAliases, keyAliasesRes);
    }

Comment: here are the variables: 
    `@MockBean
    KeyManagementRepositoryImpl keyManagementRepository;

    @Autowired
    public KeyManagementServiceImpl keyManagementService = new KeyManagementServiceImpl(keyManagementRepository); `

Comment: Don't use `@Autowired` when creating this `keyManagementService` instance. Just `private KeyManagementService keyManagementService = new  KeyManagementServiceImpl(keyManagementRepository);`.